# My kids see my phone's location on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, privacy, geolocation, google-family-link

Yesterday my kids showed me that **they can see my Android phone's location** in the Google Maps app on their phones. Their phones are managed by Google Family Link because they are under 13.

They can also see the location of my wife's phone, but nobody else - and not each other.

I found no way of disabling this feature, and it's really disturbing.

Comment: You can manage gps permissions (not sure google may by-pass)